# How to print element values when iterating through XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, iteration

I am iterating through the results of a service call to yahoo news thus:

```
    //Send service request
    if (!$yahooResults = file_get_contents($yahooRequest)) {
      echo 'Error processing service request';
    }

    //Read result into xml document
    $yahooResultXml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $yahooResultXml->loadXML($yahooResults);

    //Build page
    include_once('components/pageHeader.php');
    echo 'Search Results';
    //echo $yahooResultXml->saveHTML();
    //Iterate over each Result node
    $stories = $yahooResultXml->getElementsByTagName('Result');
    foreach ($stories as $story) {
      //Title
      //Summary
      //Url
      //Source
      //Language
      //Publish Date
      //Modification Date
    }

    include_once('components/pageFooter.php');
```

Each Title is in a Title node within a Result Node. I cannot figure out how to simply echo the content of the Title node!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the first user comment at [PHP: DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

> $items =
>   $doc->getElementsByTagName('item'); 
>       $headlines = array();
>
> ```
> foreach($items as $item) { 
>     $headline = array(); 
>
>     if($item->childNodes->length) { 
>         foreach($item->childNodes as $i) { 
>             $headline[$i->nodeName] =
> ```
>
> $i->nodeValue; 
>               } 
>           }
>
> ```
>     $headlines[] = $headline; 
> }
> ```